# Is it possible to use nested / namespaced query variables in a GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollostack

I'd like to namespace / nest query variables like this:

```
query ($params: {$id: ID!}) {
  getUser(id: $params.id) {
    email
    username
  }
}
```

with the variables:

```
{
  "params": {
    "id": "42"
  }
}
```

but it's not a valid query.

However a query like:

```
query ($id: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    email
    username
  }
}
```

with the variables:

```
{
  "id": "42"
}
```

will work just fine.

The reason I want to do this is to automatically send in [query options](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#graphql-options) into the ApolloReact `graphql` higher order component with the `params` prop from that is applied to the wrapped component from react router. This question essentially has nothing to do with react router, apart from the fact that the `params` prop is applied to the component by react router.

ApolloReact will try to use the props from the component to automatically build the variables object, and since `id` is nested in `props` it can't find it.

The alternative is to specifically define where to find `id`, by defining an `options` method that receives `ownProps` and returns the variables object in `graphql` but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use the fields of that composite type in the query.

I think your best option will be to create the following function:

`const options = ({params: variables}) => ({variables})`

and export the wrapped component like so:

`export default graphql(QUERY, {options})(Component)`

That way the params property passed by react-router will become the variables object passed to the query and you can use it like this:

```
<Component id="1" otherVar="some value"/>
```

With the regular query:

```
query ($id: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    email
    username
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not trying to use an input that holds everything, rather I'm trying to leverage the default functionality that Apollo React provides: "By default, graphql will attempt to pick up any missing variables from the query from ownProps".

Comment: Sure! removed that part and added the actual result that you wanted so it would make more sense.